# how can i get all data of user stored in datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Here, I have this datastore query which show the data of user according to their user id by filter option to particular user.

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Query query = new Query("EventDetail");
query.addFilter("Member", FilterOperator.EQUAL, user.getUserId());
List<Entity> events = datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(10));
```

But I want the datastore query to show data of all user that they have added like this. This does not work.

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Query query = new Query("EventDetail");
List<Entity> events = datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(10));
```

So, How can i get all data of users stored in the datastore.

Comment: So are you just trying to get a list of *all* EventDetail entities?  In what way does your second example not work?

Comment: In what way does your second query not work? Does it throw an error, does it only return a few results, does it return the wrong results?

Comment: @tx802 yes i want to get a list of all data from EventDetail entity

Comment: @lanGSY my query does not return any data

Answer (score 0):

Your query is very simple and seems to be correct.
If you don't get any data, just check that you have already saved some EventDetail in your datastore.
Check if your kind name is "EventDetail" in your datastore, and not "eventDetail" (the first letter is capitalized or not ?)
Have you tried this code : [How to fetch all entities in App engine datastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920155/how-to-fetch-all-entities-in-app-engine-datastore/4941727#4941727)

Comment: yes, I have already many data in the EventDetail entity. But there is problems in attributes of the entity.

Comment: What kind of problem ? Does it throw an exception, like IanGSY asked before ?

Comment: It does not show any error. the fetch data shows empty.