# howto crawl all comments of single clip from youtube, more than 100 page

Tags: javascript, youtube, web-crawler

I need to crawl down all of the comments (more than 2,600,000 comments, over 5000 pages) for PSY's Gangnam Style Video from YouTube, see:  http://www.youtube.com/all_comments?v=9bZkp7q19f0

**The problem is:**

1) If I use gdata service, google provides only no more than 1000 comment feeds

2) If I directly crawl html tags from:

```
site(http://www.youtube.com/all_comments?v=9bZkp7q19f0&page=$(page))
```

by increasing the page parameter, it would fail after page #101, where no comments 
    displayed on the page.

So plz everyone, how can I get around this problem?

P.S: My crawler is implemented as a chrome extension using javascript, which checks the comment tags of the loaded page, and then loading next page.

Comment: I am not exactly sure, but don't you have to pay for more comments? I think that's the reason why is there a limit.

Comment: thanks for your advice, but i'm not familiar with buying service quota from google; you got any such kinda experience ? or where can i find related doc ?

Comment: [stackoverflow - how to fetch more than 1000](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264154/google-appengine-how-to-fetch-more-than-1000) - Does this help you? :-)

Comment: Did you try [TubeKit](http://www.tubekit.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to extract the data by crawling the pages and hacking the code for the problems encountered, but that is not the proper way.

You should use the [youtube api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_comments#Retrieve_comments) for this and check the other [developer resources](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_audience) concerning to this.

Comment: i already tried the youtube gdata api, but google limits the returned result length to no more than 1000, check [YouTube API Ref](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference?hl=en)...and even i manually click on the all_comments page, i still cannot navigate to #102 page.

Comment: Were you able to fetch even 1000 comments. I can fetch only 99. :-/