# App Engine Datastore Remote API causing infinite loop

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Datastore table with 1024 entries in it, and a python code that connects to GAE using the remote api, and iterates over the table:

```
from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApi(None, '/_ah/remote_api', auth_func, 'my-app.appspot.com')

for entry in MyTable.all():
    // do something
```

The code worked perfectly for a year, but today when the table size grew to 1024, this code started causing an infinite loop (after the last entry is fetched), and millions of requests to `/_ah/remote_api` which made me reach the daily quota.

I solved the problem by iterating over the table in chunks, but I'm interested what causes it, especially because according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264154/google-appengine-how-to-fetch-more-than-1000), fetching of more than 1000 records should be possible.

Any ideas?